# Is there a way to run Android's security provider on computer''s JRE?

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I want to experiment with different security providers from Android (Crypto, BC, harmonyjsee, etc.) on PC. However, the code always throws a NoSuchProviderException, since my jre doesn't contain those android providers. Is there a way to get android provider working on PC? I don't want to run android emulation since my computer is very slow.

Comment: You need to include those libraries in your program's classpath for the SPI mechanism to find them.

Comment: Where can I get those libraries? I can't find the said providers in Android SDK's Android.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a security provider to be available, you have to:

1. Install the provider classes

   - either put them on the normal classpath
   - or put them in your JRE's lib/ext directory
2. Register the provider

   - either statically by adding a line `security.provider.n=masterClassName` in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security`
   - or dynamically by calling [`java.security.Security.addProvider()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#addProvider-java.security.Provider-)

Source: [Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide, Installing Providers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderInstalling)

Comment: AND the provider has to be signed, with a key whose public key has been signed by Oracle.